# iOS - How do i create one app which will allow users to download multiple games

Tags: ios, xcode

We create a lot of Spot Differences games and recently app store contacted me and told me it is a type of spam. Instead they want me to create one app, in which users can download all our games.

Is there an simple way to do this? Coding all games into one will make it a very large and heavy game.

I have seen casino games where users can download different games and play. I am looking to achieve something similar but do not know where to start.

Thanks.